Do neurons connect to other neurons that occur in a way that is clustered together?
I've read that on average, a neuron in the human brain is connected to about 1,000 other neurons. The "usual" diagram of a neuron contains only one axon which may have many terminal buttons.
Putting these two together, is it true that these 1,000 other connections occur in a way that is highly clustered together? After all, there is only one axon, so the neuron can't connect to disparate parts of the brain.
Reference image: https://opentextbc.ca/introductiontopsychology/wp-content/uploads/sites/9/2013/11/6a3f0732c22683476ea201ffc5e428ad.jpg

Braitenberg and Schuz (1998) argued that the cortex is a mixing machine: every neuron can contact almost any other, arguing against clustering as that would decrease the information storage capacity. Both functional and structural studies have provided evidence of some bias for synapses to form towards previously contacted synaptic partners (e.g. Markram et al. 1997, Kasthuri et al. 2015), but they all have sampling limitations. Neurons can preferentially connect. But do they in fact, above chance levels? Huge samples with limited selection bias are required.
